# C++ How To Make a Dictionary With Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

I want to make a dictionary but I can not output 2 tree in my code 
and I don't know what to do next:

```
WORD *t1 = NULL;
WORD *t2 = NULL;
WORD *t = NULL;

void InsertWordEN(WORD *t1, TD x)
{
    if(t1 == NULL)
    {
        WORD *temp;
        temp = new WORD;
        strcpy(temp->data.EN, x.EN);
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        t1 = temp;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (strcmp(t1->data.EN, x.EN) == 1)
        {
            InsertWordEN(t1->left,x);
        }
        else if(strcmp(t1->data.EN, x.EN) == 0)
        {
            InsertWordEN(t1->right,x);
        }
    }
}
void InsertWordVN(WORD *t2, TD x)
{
    if(t2 == NULL)
    {
        WORD *temp;
        temp = new WORD;
        strcpy(temp->data.VN, x.VN);
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        t2 = temp;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (strcmp(t2->data.VN, x.VN) == 1)
        {
            InsertWordVN(t2->left,x);
        }
        else if(strcmp(t2->data.VN, x.VN) == 0)
        {
            InsertWordVN(t2->right,x);
        }
    }
}

void InsertWord(TD &x)
{
    cout<<"\EN: "; cin>>x.EN;
    InsertWordEN(t1,x);
    cout<<"\nVN: "; cin>>x.VN;
    InsertWordEN(t2,x);
}

void OutputWord_NLR(WORD *t)
{
    if(t1 != NULL)
    {
        cout<<t1->data.EN<<" "; 
        OutputWord_NLR(t1->left);
        OutputWord_NLR(t1->right);
    }
    else if(t2 != NULL)
    {
        cout<<t2->data.VN<<" "; 
        OutputWord_NLR(t2->left);
        OutputWord_NLR(t2->right);
    }
}   
int main()
{
    int select; TD x;
    InsertWord(x);
    cout<<"\nOutput Tree EN and VN";
    OutputWord_NLR(t);  
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I think OutputWord_NLR function is wrong ? 
BTS. It's too hard for me . I'm trying to understand it :) 
Sorry ! It's seems too long . So I can't send at all my code

Comment: A BST is basically already a dictionary. What do you mean by "but I can not output 2 tree in my code"?

Comment: If you're stumped and can't progress it's usually a good opportunity to try and write unit tests for your code. By putting together tested, confirmed-working bits of code you can get a lot farther than trying to assemble it all out of unproven parts.

Comment: If this is C++ code it's discouraging to see `strcmp` in there. Use `std::string` whenever possible.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's mean I can't show t1 and t2 on my screen... it's not working and not show any error

Comment: I recommend using an existing data structure, such as `std::set` or `std::map`.

Comment: Also, since you are programming in C++, prefer to use `std::string`.  You can convert to `char *` (for API) by using `std::string::c_str()`.  The `std::string` handles reallocation, buffer overflow and copying for you.